# How to set items order in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I have a List of string. e.g. "abc", "pqr", "xyz" in this order.
A StackPanel is data bound to this list.
I want to display the list in a StackPanel vertically but in reverse order from top to bottom

```
"xyz"
"pqr"
"abc"
```

Is there a way to do this in xaml or do I have to reorder my list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373343/sorting-elements-in-a-stackpanel-wpf look there, similar question

Comment: Can I ask why you want to reorder them in XAML?

Comment: The same list is used at multiple places in the View. At one place I need to show it in Left to Right direction and in another place I need to show in Bottom to Top direction. So I did not want to change the list. I thought there will be a simple property in StackPanel to set this direction. But I guess I am wrong.

Comment: I cannot find it now but I saw a really slick solution on SO where a they used scaling -1, 1 to reverse the order.

Comment: You can take a look at this [question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405473/reversed-listbox-without-sorting/7409586#7409586) which shows how to use a converter to reverse a list you're binding to. It should be easy to extend the converter to support sorting, permutations, etc though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No, the `StackPanel` will display them in the order in which they are enumerated.  So you have a couple of options as I see it:

1) Re-order your list

2) Change your binding, or apply a [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that does the re-order on the fly. This of course requires coding the converter, but once it's written you can re-use it in your XAML as required without having to modify individual windows, code-behinds, etc.

Comment: In case of `2)`, I presume the converter should also listen to collection modification events when binding to an `ObservableCollection`. An advantage of [Charlie's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10964360/590790) is this works 'out of the box'.

Answer (score 5):

This is very hackish, but seems to work.  Set the stackpanel's layout transform to rotate 180.  Then each child's layout transform also to 180.

```
<StackPanel Name="pnlLayers">
<StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
</StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
```

(in my case, I had a custom user control as the row)

```
<UserControl.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
</UserControl.LayoutTransform>
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `ScaleTransform` and `ScaleX="-1"`. This feels a bit more intuitive.

Comment: I also don't feel this is a 'hacky' solution. It seems to be the only solution in case you properly want to follow [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), since I don't feel the view model should change just because the view changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate a `StackPanel` using a `DockPanel` with `LastChildFill="False"` attribute and setting the `Dock` attached property on every child element. By using `Dock.Right` you can stack elements horizontally in reverse order (i.e right-to-left); using `Dock.Bottom` stacks vertically in reverse order (i.e. bottom-to-top).

For more details and example code, see my answer to [StackPanel reverse order - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71782166/660896).