# StackPanel reverse order - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I am trying to reverse the order of which the children appear in the StackPanel. I want to be able to add new children (whilst running the app) to the top of the list instead of the bottom. I have tried using various XAML code but nothing worked.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475629/how-to-set-items-order-in-stackpanel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
stackPanel.Children.Insert(0, uiElement);
```

This will insert the element at the head of the list.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.insert.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to stack elements in opposite order than they are listed as children using a `DockPanel`. This should allow you do what you want entirely in XAML (no need for code-behind). This could be helpful if you're binding to a collection and you don't want to reverse the order of the collection or don't want to insert items at the head of the collection.

When you specify the `Dock` attached property on multiple child element (e.g. `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`) it will stack them on the specified edge of the panel in order, such that the first child element will be closest that edge.

### Bottom-to-top stacking

Therefore, to stack elements bottom-to-top, set the `Dock` property to `Bottom` on all the child elements and give them a fixed height. Here's an example:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="40" Content="B 1" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="40" Content="B 2" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="40" Content="B 3" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Note the use of `LastChildFill="False"` - by default the `DockPanel` will stretch the last item to fill the remaining space.

This renders as follows:

[image: Figure 2]

### Right-to-left stacking

The same also works for right-to-left ordering of elements

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DigitalElectronics.UI.Controls.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="40" Content="B 1" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="40" Content="B 2" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="40" Content="B 3" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

[image: Figure 3]