# Generic IValueConverter C# WPF usage in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, ivalueconverter

basically I used the posted Converter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405473/reversed-listbox-without-sorting) and just changed the Datatype to be a generic. How do I use the generic Converter inside XAML?

```
public class ReverseListConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public ReverseListConverter()
    {
    }

    private ObservableCollection<T> _reversedList;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _reversedList = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        var data = (ObservableCollection<T>)value;

        for (var i = data.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            _reversedList.Add(data[i]);

        data.CollectionChanged += DataCollectionChanged;

        return _reversedList;
    }

    void DataCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = (ObservableCollection<T>)sender;

        _reversedList.Clear();
        for (var i = data.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            _reversedList.Add(data[i]);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Before the Converter was generic I just used

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Mails, Converter={tools:ReverseListConverter}}"
```

Is there a way to do this with a generic Converter in XAML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can forget about making a generic converter a markup extension, you cannot simply create generic objects in XAML ([there are *some* cases in which you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956431.aspx) in .NET 4, don't know if anything changed in 4.5).

One way to create an instance would be using a helper class which contructs an instance for you (i wrote one in [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235421/how-do-i-set-wpf-xaml-forms-design-datacontext-to-class-that-uses-generic-type/8235459#8235459)).